Does CommunityToolkit.Mvvm work for VB.NET?
I just started studying CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package (aka MVVM Toolkit) and reading the introduction documentation it seemed like it would work for VB.NET as well:
Introduction to the MVVM Toolkit - Community Toolkits for .NET

But I wrote a VB.NET test project (I installed the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package on the latest stable version 8.2.2) and it looks like it's not automatically generating the observable code:
Imports CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class MyViewModel : Inherits ObservableObject

   <ObservableProperty>
   Private id As Integer

   <ObservableProperty>
   <NotifyPropertyChangedFor(NameOf(FullName))>
   Private firstName As String

   <ObservableProperty>
   <NotifyPropertyChangedFor(NameOf(FullName))>
   Private lastName As String

   Public ReadOnly Property FullName As String
      Get
         Return $"{firstName} {lastName}"
      End Get
   End Property

End Class


So, I tried doing exactly the same in a C# project and it worked:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

internal partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{

   [ObservableProperty]
   private int id;

   [ObservableProperty]
   [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
   private string firstName;

   [ObservableProperty]
   [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
   private string lastName;

   public string FullName => $"{firstName} {lastName}";

}


So, does the automatic code generation for ObservableObject and ObservableProperty work for VB.NET or not?

I didn't find any mention of VB.NET in the documentation, other than that excerpt I mentioned in the question, but I did a search now in the source code of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package (GitHub - CommunityToolkit/dotnet: .NET Community Toolkit) and it seems that code generation really only works for C#:
dotnet / src / CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators / ComponentModel / ObservablePropertyGenerator.cs
namespace CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators;

[Generator(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public sealed partial class ObservablePropertyGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        // [ ... ]

        if (!context.SemanticModel.Compilation.HasLanguageVersionAtLeastEqualTo(LanguageVersion.CSharp8))
        {
            return default;
        }

        // [ ... ]
    }
}

Note the attribute used for the class, Generator(LanguageNames.CSharp), and the section that checks that the language version is at least C# 8, Compilation.HasLanguageVersionAtLeastEqualTo(LanguageVersion.CSharp8).

You could file a feature request in the Git repo. As far as I know, VB has Source Generators as well.

I just did that, thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/888

They answered the feature request with this message: "Hey there! Unfortunately this is not planned and it's not a feature we are going to add".
